# Cannot get correct information in openssl from webmin server

Tags: ssl, openssl, webmin

I have a webmin server installed on a debian 10 distribution.
There are installed different website, es.:

```
website1.com
website2.com
website3.com
website4.com
website5.com
```

I want to get information about ssl with this command

```
openssl s_client -connect website3.com:443
openssl s_client -connect website5.com:443
```

I get correct information only if I have a **linux** client...
With **OSX** or **Windows** platform, I always have information about website1.com(!)

I think it's a server side problem, but I don't know where....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this most likely isn't a server problem, and I see the same symptom - as expected - both on my Mac and on a Ubuntu 18.04 server when testing.

The `openssl s_client -connect <<hostname|ip>:port>` simply attempts to connect to a TLS enabled listener via its DNS name or its IP address.

If you host multiple domains behind the same listener, you need to specify which service you want to reach by appending the argument `-servername <websitex.com>`.

The full command to connect to the looks like this:

`openssl s_client -connect websitex.com:443 -servername website3.com`, where `websitex` can be substituted with any valid DNS name or alias pointing at the relevant listener.